# php dblib mssql select. Не выполняется запрос к определенным таблицам

Tags: php, sql-server, select

Имеется база oktell на ms sql server 2008.
Нужно получить из нее данные на хостинге (linux, apache, dblib, php).

Собственно, к базе подключился (вроде как), смог получить список таблиц INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
Но запрос конкретно к таблице не проходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, в какую сторону копать.

Код подключения примерно такой:

```
class pdo_dblib_mssql{

public $db;
public $cTransID;
public $childTrans = array();

public function __construct($hostname, $port, $dbname, $username, $pwd){
    $this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->port = $port;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->pwd = $pwd;
    $this->connect();
}

/* ......... Здесь другие ф-ции класса ........... */

public function connect(){
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO ("dblib:host=$this->hostname:$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->pwd");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //$this->logsys .= "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        //echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}}

$dbh = new pdo_dblib_mssql('111.111.111.11', '1433', 'oktell', 'entername', 'password');
```

/* 
    entername - имя входа, находится в Безопасность -> имена входа. 
    членство в роли базы данных для oktell - на всякий случай все галочки (включая db_owner)
*/

Код запросов (первый работает, второй - нет):

```
echo ($stmt = $dbh->db->query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES")) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // yes
echo ($stmt = $dbh->db->query("SELECT * FROM oktell.dbo.[6D]")) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все галочки надо было ставить. Оказалось, можно одновременно дать разрешение пользователю на запросы и ограничить его в них (O_o), причем последнее будет решающим.
В заблуждение ввела возможность узнать имена таблиц базы без разрешения на select.
Зашел в SSMS испод пользователя через sql авторизацию и при попытке посмотреть базы узнал название ошибки.